# Any cure for blurred vision after sitting with eyes half-open?

Tags: personal-practice, meditation-practicalities, meditation-effects

I get slightly blurred vision after a long sit during which I have my eyes half-closed (as in Zazen style). It can last for more than an hour and is a practical drag, and also creates a slightly woozy feeling.

Any re-focusing eye exercise anyone know of?

Thank you

Joe

Comment: Hi, interested to find out the benefits of keeping eyes half closed.

Comment: My recommendation would be that visit your GP, an ophthalmologist or at least an optometrist. Blurred vision for more than an hour is not a good sign.

Comment: Hi Kaveenga: the half-closed technique is seen as preventing the sitter from falling asleep, or indulging too much in inner fantasy etc., balancing the inner and outer experiences etc. At least that's my understanding. It seems to be a particular requirement of Zazen, i.e. Japanese Zen sitting.

Answer (score 2):

Close them, would be maybe the most practical.

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me too.  It's most noticeable when the room I sit in is very dark.  I've never had that happen to me during the day, for instance, or when we have an altar set up at the zendo.  It might help to light a candle or to plug in a nightlight.  I also find that my eyes are most problematic when I look at a computer screen shortly after sitting.  Like the doctor advising a patient who felt pain when he raised his arm, the simple solution is to just not do that!  Give your eyes some time to readjust to focusing before putting a screen in front of them.